# How to set FileIO writeDynamic name with input fields?

Tags: file-io, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Dataflow to load some csv to Google Cloud Storage and I need to save some CSV files into different directories based on data values (like uuid, region, etc.).

How can I do this? Currently I'm able to add the key (from KV) in the path but I would also need some other information that currently is only available on values.

Currently this saves data to `gs://my-bucket/<uuid>/extraction.csv` but I need something like `gs://my-bucket/<uuid>/<region>/<store>/extraction.`

Example csv:

> uuid,region,store,....
>
> 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000,central,store1,foo,bar

```
.apply("Write CSV files",
                        FileIO.<String, KV<String, String>>writeDynamic()
                                .by(KV::getKey)
                                .to("gs://my-bucket")
                                .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                                .withNumShards(1)
                                .via(Contextful.fn(KV::getValue), TextIO.sink())
                                .withNaming(key -> FileIO.Write.defaultNaming(String.format("%s/extraction",key),"csv"))
                );
```

Comment: See a [more complex example of writeDynamic from Mozilla's telemetry pipeline](https://github.com/mozilla/gcp-ingestion/blob/8d1df08419b7e8bc8aa5affb2777cb6a2d27def0/ingestion-beam/src/main/java/com/mozilla/telemetry/io/Write.java#L150-L163). In that case it prepares a list of strings to `by` and then injects those into a template in the lambda passed to `withNaming`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to have `<region>` and `<store>` as part of the key as well, and then generate the right path in the function that you pass with `withNaming`.